# Cannot launch Scrapy as I keep getting "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to run a scrapy script but today when I started it I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

To fix this I added:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()
```

Now I get:

```
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

With:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Now:

```
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I've then went to my scrapy folder in Anaconda and tried adding:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'myAppName.apps.myAppNameConfig',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

This is generally for Django though so I don't think it approved.

Can someone help me get out of the array of bug errors I'm getting so I can launch scrapy?  I've been trying to launch scrapy program today but feel I'm going on an endless quest for different errors.

Am I overthinking this and it's as simple as deleting a few lines of code or a case of wrong directory?

Thanks

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()


from scrapy import cmdline


import csv
import scrapy


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


from scrapy import cmdline
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl jobs".split())
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from jobs.items import jobs

from csv import DictWriter, QUOTE_MINIMAL
from lxml import html

import requests

SEARCH_PAGE_URL = "https://www.richelieu.com/us/en/search?s=%20"
```

Comment: do you run `Scrapy` in `Django` ? Can you run `Django` without `Scrapy` ? `Django` needs to generate project `django-admin startproject <project-name>`

Comment: @furas I created a new project and that solved it for me.  Maybe corruption issues.  Not sure, I don't actually use Django which is why this error threw me off.